# Specifying an 'optgroup' with watir-webdriver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, optgroup

I've got an HTML page with the following format:

```
   <select id="name_list">
      <optgroup label="env1">
          <option value="comp1">comp1 details</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="env2">
          <option value="comp1">comp1 details</option>
      </optgroup> 
   </select>
```

And trying to click on the option with value=comp1 which is inside optgroup-env2 specifically. Is there any way to specify this path? Note that both 'options' values are exactly the same under the different 'optgroup' nodes...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate an optgroup like any other element. Then you can search within that group for your option.

```
browser.optgroup(:label =>'env2').option(:value => 'comp1').select
```

**Update** - It looks like there is a bug in watir-webdriver that prevents the above from working.

When creating the locator for the label, watir-webdriver calls the following [method](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb#L273-L274):

```
def should_use_label_element?
  @selector[:tag_name] != "option"
end
```

For the optgroup, this returns false, which means that watir goes and looks for an associated label element (rather than checking the attribute).

As a temporary workaround, you could use css:

```
browser.element(:css => 'optgroup[label="env2"]').option(:value => 'comp1').select
```

A bug has been created for this issue (see [Issue 219](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/219)).

Comment: Thank you very much Justin, for the explanation, the raised bug and the workaround!! I'll give it a go on Monday...

Comment: Hi again, just tried the workaround and getting this error...

NoMethodError: undefined method `option' for #<Watir::HTMLElementCollection:0x693f87b1>

if I don't put the .element(). part then I am able to do browswer.option correctly (although it picks the 1st occurrence rather than the correct one).

Does that error make sense to you? or can you think of another workaround?

Comment: Based on the exception, it sounds like you have a typo? The exception suggests you used `elements` rather than `element` (ie you have an extra `s`). Can you double-check?

Comment: Note that a fix was checked in to the watir-webdriver repository. I am not sure that the updated gem has been released yet, but you could copy the fix into your code (so that you do not need the workaround).

Comment: Awesome, user-error with that extra 's', I couldn't find the difference myself... Many thanks again!!